# How to access $parent of ng-repeat within ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I have a ng-repeat inside a ng-repeat with a ng-include inside of the inner ng-repeat. Inside that ng-include, I want to access the outer ng-repeat with $parent. Here is my sample code:

index.html

```
<div ng-repeat="population in populations">
   <div ng-repeat="person in population">
      <div ng-include="person.url"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

one_person.html ("person.url" resolves to this)

```
<div> Your population id is {{ $parent.$index }}</div>
```

I am not able to access `$parent.$index` from that `ng-include`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) create scope so as [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

Try like this

```
<div ng-repeat="population in populations">
   <div ng-repeat="person in population">
      <div ng-include="person.url" onload="parent=$parent.$parent"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**person.url**

```
<div> Your population id is {{ parent.$index }}</div>
```